# Ubuntu 14.04 Digital Audio stops working

Tags: ubuntu, audio, spdif

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 HTPC for quite some time. It's connected by toslink to a logitech z5500. Sound was working, but suddenly stopped...

I've followed almost every guide and how-to to fix my sound, but it won't seem to help.

Some information:

```
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.63
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Sun Jun 29 14:43:40 UTC 2014


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      System manufacturer
Product Name:      System Product Name
Product Version:   System Version
Firmware Version:  0904


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    3.13.0-30-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k3.13.0-30-generic
Library version:    1.0.27.2
Utilities version:  1.0.27.2


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7c10000 irq 45


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)


!!Advanced information - PCI Vendor/Device/Subsystem ID's
!!-------------------------------------------------------

00:1b.0 0403: 8086:1e20 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: 1043:8415


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_hda_intel: model=auto


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : 1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : auto,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 1
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : N
    snoop : Y


!!HDA-Intel Codec information
!!---------------------------
--startcollapse--

Codec: VIA VT1708S
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x11060397
Subsystem Id: 0x10438415
Revision Id: 0x100000
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    formats [0x0]:
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=1, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x10 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Front Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="VT1708S Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x2a, nsteps=0x2a, stepsize=0x05, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x2a 0x2a]
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x11 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Surround Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x2a, nsteps=0x2a, stepsize=0x05, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x2a 0x2a]
  Converter: stream=8, channel=2
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x12 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Default PCM Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Device: name="VT1708S Digital", type="HDMI", device=3
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: GenLevel
  Digital category: 0x2
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x13 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="VT1708S Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x0b, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x9c 0x9c]
  Converter: stream=4, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x17
Node 0x14 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x0b, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x8b 0x8b]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x1e
Node 0x15 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: GenLevel
  Digital category: 0x2
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x16 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20050b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Rear Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Rear Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Front Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=4, ofs=0
  Control: name="Front Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=4, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=3, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=3, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x17 0x17] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x1f 0x1f] [0x83 0x83] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 7
     0x10 0x1f 0x1a 0x1b 0x1e 0x1d 0x25
Node 0x17 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300501: Stereo
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 6
     0x1f 0x1a* 0x1b 0x1e 0x1d 0x16
Node 0x18 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x30050d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Surround Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x11
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x410110f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x18
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Control: name="Rear Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Rear Mic Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00002334: IN OUT Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 100
  Pin Default 0x01a19036: [Jack] Mic at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Pink
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x6
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=03, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x26
Node 0x1b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Control: name="Line Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00002334: IN OUT Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 100
  Pin Default 0x0181303e: [Jack] Line In at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Blue
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0xe
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=05, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x18
Node 0x1c [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Front Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Out Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0001001c: OUT HP EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x01014010: [Jack] Line Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Green
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x16
Node 0x1d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Front Headphone Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0000233c: IN OUT HP Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 100
  Pin Default 0x0221401f: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Front
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Green
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0xf
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x16 0x25*
Node 0x1e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Front Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Front Mic Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000233c: IN OUT HP Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 100
  Pin Default 0x02a19037: [Jack] Mic at Ext Front
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Pink
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x7
  Pin-ctls: 0x21: IN VREF_50
  Unsolicited: tag=04, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x16* 0x25
Node 0x1f [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400401: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x503701f0: [N/A] CD at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x20 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400701: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="HDMI Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x12
Node 0x21 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400701: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="SPDIF Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x074511f0: [Jack] SPDIF Out at Ext Rear Panel
    Conn = Optical, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x15
Node 0x22 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x410160f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Orange
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x26
Node 0x23 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x410120f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Grey
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x27
Node 0x24 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Center Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="LFE Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=2, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x2a, nsteps=0x2a, stepsize=0x05, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x2a 0x2a]
  Converter: stream=8, channel=4
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x25 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="VT1708S Alt Analog", type="Audio", device=2
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x2a, nsteps=0x2a, stepsize=0x05, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x2a 0x2a]
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x26 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x30050d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Center Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="LFE Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=2, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x24
Node 0x27 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x30050d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x25
Codec: Intel PantherPoint HDMI
Address: 3
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x80862806
Subsystem Id: 0x80860101
Revision Id: 0x100000
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    formats [0x0]:
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0, Clock-stop-OK
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled GenLevel
  Digital category: 0x2
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x05 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x80]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x58560010: [N/A] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x02
Node 0x06 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x80]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x58560020: [N/A] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x03
Node 0x07 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Control: name="HDMI/DP,pcm=7 Jack", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="ELD", index=0, device=7
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560030: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x04
Node 0x08 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
--endcollapse--


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  9 Jun 29 16:35 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  8 Jun 29 16:35 /dev/snd/hwC0D0
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  7 Jun 29 16:35 /dev/snd/hwC0D3
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  6 Jun 29 16:41 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  5 Jun 29 16:41 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  3 Jun 29 16:35 /dev/snd/pcmC0D2p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  4 Jun 29 16:41 /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  2 Jun 29 16:41 /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  1 Jun 29 16:35 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 33 Jun 29 16:35 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Jun 29 16:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 260 Jun 29 16:35 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Jun 29 16:35 pci-0000:00:1b.0 -> ../controlC0


!!ALSA configuration files
!!------------------------

!!User specific config file (~/.asoundrc)

pcm.!default {

   type plug
   slave {
       pcm "hdmi"
   }

}

!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: VT1708S Alt Analog [VT1708S Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: VT1708S Digital [VT1708S Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card 0 [PCH]

Card hw:0 'PCH'/'HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7c10000 irq 45'
  Mixer name    : 'Intel PantherPoint HDMI'
  Components    : 'HDA:11060397,10438415,00100000 HDA:80862806,80860101,00100000'
  Controls      : 52
  Simple ctrls  : 21
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 42
  Mono: Playback 42 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 42
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 42 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 42 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 252 [99%] [-0.60dB]
  Front Right: Playback 252 [99%] [-0.60dB]
Simple mixer control 'Front',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 42
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 42 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 42 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Front Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch cswitch cswitch-joined cswitch-exclusive
  Capture exclusive group: 0
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono: Capture [off]
  Front Left: Playback 3 [10%] [-30.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 3 [10%] [-30.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Front Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Surround',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 42
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 42 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 42 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Center',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 42
  Mono: Playback 42 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'LFE',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 42
  Mono: Playback 42 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Line',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch cswitch cswitch-joined cswitch-exclusive
  Capture exclusive group: 0
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono: Capture [off]
  Front Left: Playback 31 [100%] [12.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 31 [100%] [12.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958 Default PCM',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 31
  Front Left: Capture 28 [90%] [25.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Capture 28 [90%] [25.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Disabled'
Simple mixer control 'Channel Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: '2ch' '4ch' '6ch'
  Item0: '6ch'
Simple mixer control 'Dynamic Power-Control',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Enabled'
Simple mixer control 'Independent HP',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Disabled'
Simple mixer control 'Loopback Mixing',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Disabled'
Simple mixer control 'Rear Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch cswitch cswitch-joined cswitch-exclusive
  Capture exclusive group: 0
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono: Capture [on]
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Rear Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
```

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=deeefc68ea490958d718b9b1ce3fe63bcfa7da5e

Comment: mainstream@dopamine-pc:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: VT1708S Alt Analog [VT1708S Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: VT1708S Digital [VT1708S Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: I would encourage you to move this question to the Ubuntu Exhange site (AskUbuntu, don't recall the name). This is not a bad or off topic question, but the help there with such specific questions would likely do well.

Comment: This happened to my Ubuntu Laptop before; have you tried restarting it?